# Placement script for dwm

Tags: x-dwm

`dwm` have different screen mentioned on the `dmenu` (the bar at the top) as `1` `2` `3` `4`...
I wanted write a script that open for example application `A` on screen `1` and application `B` and `C` on screen `2`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://dwm.suckless.org/customisation/rules has some examples which might be helpful.